# Firebase firestore auth callback Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): No document to update:

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have an Email, Google and Facebook authentication in Firebase and I want to create a Firestore records of users who sign in with Google or Facebook.

My code is as follows:

```
exports.onUserCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  if (user.providerId !== 'password') {
    console.log('onusercreate start')
    await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      email: user.email,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      user_name: '',
      full_name: user.displayName,
      phone_number: '',
      uid: user.uid,
      friends_count: 0,
      posts: 0,
      fcm_token: '',
      chats_initiated: [],
      rank: 'Goon',
      rah_points: 0,
      last_seen: '',
      push_notification_settings: 'ON',
    })
  }
})
```

This code throws the following error in the console:

```
Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): No document to update: projects/teambeforeself-b1c79/databases/(default)/documents/users/oe7d4MMaTyQ6kNDxuEdqGeamLeQ2
```

[image: console error]

The auth user is created with google sign in but the Firestore document is not being created.

The logs in Firebase Cloud Functions are as follows:

```
2:58:51.762 pm onUserCreate Function execution started
2:58:52.116 pm onUserCreate onusercreate start
2:58:53.454 pm onUserCreate Function execution took 1693 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

Comment: Where did you get the error from? The logs show that the functions finished with `ok`. The error would make sense if you used `updated` instead of `set`. The error is usual if you try to update an document that doesn't exist. It should not happen when you use `set`.

Comment: I am getting error on browser. I am using react

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): No document to update: projects/teambeforeself-b1c79/databases/(default)/documents/users/FiY0BPz76bUqMP81XEdosemiBe33

Comment: Can you pls make a screenshot of the error. Usualy you don't get clout function errors on your browser beside the logs in the Firebase Console.

Comment: The error is now coming in console: https://ibb.co/KNngsQf

Comment: If you can remotely join my computer, then please do ... https://meet.google.com/tqy-eoyq-nme

Comment: I will show you some code and error

Comment: @ManavSethi Please review this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60075305/unhandled-rejection-firebaseerror-no-document-to-update) that describes what Tarik Huber already mentioned in the first comment. Does it answer your question?

Comment: I was using a wrong Firebase config (of a different project). So bad!